# Questions about business logic layer and data access layer in a project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio

I would separate the BLL from DAL as a best practice. I interact between BLL and DAL via interface.
Example:

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    void Add(Product myProduct);
    Product Get(string name);
    Product GetById(int id);
}
```

where business object Product is:

```
public class Product
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The BLL class is:

```
public class ProductManager
{
     private readonly IProductRepository productRepository;

     public ProductManager(IProductRepository productRepository)
     {
          this.productRepository = productRepository ?? throw new Exception("message");
     }

    public void AddProduct(Product myProduct)
    {
        try
        {                  
            // Here code validation ecc....

            // Add product to database
            productRepository.Add(myProduct);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception  
        }
    } 

    public Product GetProduct(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            // Here code to validation ecc....

            // Get product from database
            var product = _productRepository.Get(name);

            return product;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception  
        }
    }
     // ecc ecc
}
```

where DAL (i would use Entity Framework) is:

```
public ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    public void Add(Product myProduct)
    {
        using(var dbContext = MyDbContext())
        {
            var dbProduct = new PRODUCTS
            {
                NAME = myProduct.Name,
                PRICE = myProduct.Price
            }

            dbContext.PRODUCT.Add(dbProduct);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    // ecc ecc
}
```

Now I have some questions:
- Is this the correct implementation?
- If I want insert a product but I want to check if a product with the same name is on db, do I first call the Get method in BLL and then call Add method (the db context is open and closed each time, is an overload?) or I can insert logic in DAL like:

```
var dbProduct = dbContext.PRODUCTS.FirstOrDefault(p => p.NAME == name);

if(dbProduct == null) .... // insert else throw exception
```

In the latter case, however, if a change the dal the bll logig would no work anymore.
-Is it right to use EntityFramework in this way, or do I lose all the benefits of linq?
Sorry, but i'm very confused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Name` of a product needs to be unique, there should be unique constraint at your database. Otherwise concurrent writes could insert the same product name twice into the product table, even when there is a test in the client code which tries to avoid this.

But if there is such a constraint, testing for uniqueness in the DAL layer (and throwing an exception in case the product name was used before) is superfluous, since the `dbContext` will throw an exception anyway in case the constraint is violated. So putting such a test into the DAL is not inherently wrong, but does not actually bring any real benefit.